# Solve integro differential equation numerically

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, integral-equations

I want to solve the following equation numerically:

[image]

with initial condition y[0]=0 and y'[0]=0

I tried to do so by using the NDSolve function:

`eqn = Derivative[2][y][x] == 1+y[x] - Integrate[Derivative[1][y][x - t]/sqrt[t], {t, 0, x}];
NDSolve[{eqn, y[0] == 0, Derivative[1][y][0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 1}]`

But it seems like Matlab cannot solve it directly. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You mean Mathematica cannot solve? You wrote Matlab

Comment: Convert it to a regular ODE and then feed it to `NDSolve[]`.

Comment: `sqrt` should be `Sqrt`. This isn't main issue here of course.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comment above, `sqrt` should be `Sqrt` and *Matlab* should be *Mathematica*, these aren't the main issue here of course. Currently `NDSolve` can't handle the problem, but we can solve the equation with the help of `LaplaceTransform`:

```
teqn = LaplaceTransform[eqn, x, s] /. Rule @@@ ic
tsol = Solve[teqn, LaplaceTransform[y[x], x, s]][[1, 1, -1]]
(* 1/(s (-1 + Sqrt[\[Pi]] Sqrt[s] + s^2)) *)
```

`InverseLaplaceTransform` can't handle `tsol`, so I turned to [this numeric Laplace inversion package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5026/):

```
Plot[FT[(s \[Function] #) &@tsol, x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally, `DSolve` in *v11* can solve this equation *in principle*, but sadly it doesn't give the correct answer in this case, I think there's no doubt it's a bug:

```
eqn = y''[x] == 1 + y[x] - Integrate[y'[x - t]/Sqrt[t], {t, 0, x}];

ic = {y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0};

sol[x_] = y[x]/.First@DSolve[{eqn, ic}, y@x, x]
(* 1/2 E^-x (-1 + E^x)^2 *)
Plot[{sol@x, FT[(s \[Function] #) &@tsol, x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Output of DSolve", "Numeric Solution"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What's more awkward is, if the second argument of `DSolve` is modified to `y` i.e. if we write `DSolve[{eqn, ic}, y, x]`, `DSolve` will return the input... Seems that this new feature is still unstable.

Comment: `Dsolve` gives wrong answer.Can you check it?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk You're right. `DSolve` in v11 is more unstable than I thought. Edited. Thanks for point out.