# I need to solve integro–differential equation with derivative

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

There are 2 equations a1 and a2, the difference between them is the red words part(integral term).

[image: equation a1 and a2]

Boundary x(0)=0,x'(0)=0

x'(t-u) means Bring t-u into the derivative of x ，for example, if x(t)=t^3, then x'(t-u)=3*(t-u)^2

However ,I get the same curve by different codes .so I want to know what's wrong with my code especially the integral term(red words).

The following is code of a1

```
ieqn = 1 - 6.25*10^5*x[t] + 
1.234*10^4*Integrate[x'[t - u]/Sqrt[u], {u, 0, t}] == 1.5924*x''[t];
ic = {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0};
sol = DSolve[{ieqn, ic}, x[t], t];
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 0.005}]
```

The following is code of a2

```
ieqn = 1 - 6.25*10^5*x[t] == 1.59236*x''[t];
ic = {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0};
sol = DSolve[{ieqn, ic}, x[t], t];
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 0.005}]
```

[image: same curve]
This equation is from this paper

- https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.80.134115

The following is the correct curve from this paper.

correct curve of a1:red curve arrowhead

correct curve of a2:dashed black arrowhead

As far as I know, those equation can only have numerical solution.

[image: curve in paper]

In the following website, they discussed  the same question with mine, but I think there is some wrong.

- [How to solve the differential equation with Duhamel's integral?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84885/how-to-solve-the-differential-equation-with-duhamels-integral)

At last ,I wonder what's wrong with my code especially the integral term(red words).

Comment: The units in my equations is m and s,and those in figure of paper is um and ms,so the Magnitude of my output is correct

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: Your equation is essentially the same as the one in the linked post. Have you tried the method based on Laplace transform in [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84893/1871)?

Comment: If you are using version 11.0, you are a victim of the bug described in [134465](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134465/1063).  `DSolve` instead returns unevaluated in later versions instead of just ignoring the integral.