# How to handle this constant-interval integral in ODE?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, integral-equations

The problem is to solve a system of nonlinear equations with a definite integral. $Q_i(x), i=1,2,3, x \in [-\text{max},\text{max}]$
\begin{align*} a_iQ_i''(x)-b_i(\vec{Q})-d_i\int_{-\text{max}}^{\text{max}} {\hat K Q_i dx'} = 0 \end{align*}

How can I solve the cases like $d_i=0.01,0.1$ or any other values. ***It appears to me Laplace transform doesn't help. I failed to turn it to a system of ODEs by differentiation, either. Or I missed something?***
So the question is about dealing with the integral. Any suggestions or comments? Thanks in advance.

I use the following code to easily solve the case when all $d_i=0$. The parameters are set to their typical values for my need ($\alpha_1-\alpha_{2,3}>2w_1>0=w_{2,3}$), but one can tune. $b_i=\frac{2}{\alpha_i}(Q_i-w_i)-\frac{Q_i}{|\vec{Q}|}$ and $w_i$ is constant. The form of boundary condition is not to be changed.

The integral kernal $\hat K Q_i=\frac{Q_i(x)-Q_i(x')}{(x-x')^2}$ is singular, although somehow suppressed by the nominator. If not possible to solve this, adding some small cutoff $\frac{Q_i(x)-Q_i(x')}{(x-x')^2+\delta^2}$ is OK.
When all $d_i=0$, it seems that one of $Q_2,Q_3$ stays at zero. I wonder if this holds even when $d_i\neq0$.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
max = 5.0; accur = 15;
w1 = 0.01; w2 = 0; w3 = 0; w = {w1, w2, w3};
α1 = 1.5; α2 = 1.0; α3 = 0.8; α = {\
α1, α2, α3};
Qstart = {w1 - α1/2, 0.0, 0.0}; Qend = {w1 + α1/2, 0.0, 
  0.0};
M1 = 1/α1; M2 = 1/α2; M3 = 1/α3; M = {M1, M2, M3};
dV = {2/α1 (Q1[u] - w1) - Q1[u]/Sqrt[
    Q1[u]^2 + Q2[u]^2 + Q3[u]^2], 
   2/α2 (Q2[u] - w2) - Q2[u]/Sqrt[Q1[u]^2 + Q2[u]^2 + Q3[u]^2],
    2/α3 (Q3[u] - w3) - Q3[u]/Sqrt[
    Q1[u]^2 + Q2[u]^2 + Q3[u]^2]};
s = NDSolve[{M1 Q1''[u] == dV[[1]], M2 Q2''[u] == dV[[2]], 
    M3 Q3''[u] == dV[[3]], Q1[-max] == Qstart[[1]], 
    Q2[-max] == Qstart[[2]], Q3[-max] == Qstart[[3]], 
    Q1[max] == Qend[[1]], Q2[max] == Qend[[2]], 
    Q3[max] == Qend[[3]]}, {Q1, Q2, Q3}, {u, -max, max}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> accur];
QQ = First[{Q1, Q2, Q3} /. s];
Plot[{QQ[[1]][u], QQ[[2]][u], QQ[[3]][u]}, {u, -max, max}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I can think out is to make a step backward i.e. turn to finite difference method. I'll use [`pdetoae`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the generation of difference equation.

```
V[i_] = (2 (Q[i][x] - w[i]))/α[i] - Q[i][x]/Sqrt@Sum[Q[i][x]^2, {i, 3}];
transrule = lst_List[i_] :> lst[[i]];
pararule =
  {w -> {0.01, 0, 0}, α -> {1.5, 1, 0.8}, d -> {0.01, 0.02, 0.03},
   m -> 1/α, ϵ -> 10^-6};
{Qstart, Qend} = {{w[1] - α[1]/2, 0, 0}, {w[1] + α[1]/2, 0, 0}} //. 
    pararule /. transrule;

Clear@kernel
kernel[Q[i_]@x_] = (Q[i][x] - Q[i][ξ])/((x - ξ)^2 + ϵ) /. pararule;

SetAttributes[int, Listable];
eq = Table[m[i] Q[i]''[x] - V[i] - d[i] int[Q[i]@x] == 0, {i, 3}] //. pararule /. 
   transrule;
max = 5;
points = 100;
difforder = 4;
domain = {-max, max};

{nodes, weights} = Most[NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[points, MachinePrecision]];

midgrid = Rescale[nodes, {0, 1}, domain];

intrule = int[
    qix_] :> -Subtract @@ domain weights.Map[Function[ξ, #] &@kernel[qix], midgrid];

grid = Flatten[{domain // First, midgrid, domain // Last}];

ptoafunc = pdetoae[{Q[1], Q[2], Q[3]}[x], grid, difforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
ae = del /@ ptoafunc[eq] /. intrule;
aebc = Table[
   {Q[i][domain // First] == Qstart[[i]],
    Q[i][domain // Last] == Qend[[i]]}, {i, 3}];
```

Notice that `pdetoae` can't handle integral so some extra coding has been made. The code for discretization of integral is modified from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6966/1871).

Last step is to solve the nonlinear equation system with `FindRoot`:

```
sollst = With[{initial = -2}, 
   Partition[FindRoot[{ae, aebc}, 
      Flatten[Table[{Q[i][x], initial}, {i, 3}, {x, grid}], 1], 
      MaxIterations -> 200][[All, -1]], points + 2]];

ListLinePlot[{grid, #}\[Transpose] & /@ sollst, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> {False, True}]
```

Notice there seem to be multiple solutions for the system. With `initial = -2`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With `initial = 2`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! It seems that you combined ingenuity and your arsenal for ODE/PDE. I myself tried combining my code with [an iterative method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148607/11125), which turns out to be too slow to see any output. I am a novice in both differential equation and Mathematica and not sure whether I can absorb/understand your codes. I will study it with great effort, although maybe I hope to ask sometime. If possible, it would be quite helpful if you could add more explanation. Thanks again for your time and effort!

Comment: It seems that the boundary conditions are satisfied well and solution is fast and stable. As for two solutions you show, first is reasonable while second is somehow trivial from my background knowledge since only one Q is varying. But the imaginary parts are not very small while the whole problem should be real. Is there a cure or some possible way to improve? And from your experience and expertise in ODEs, is this (real part) solution reliable in general?

Comment: I'm not familiar with finite element method or this ODE->PDE->AE approach. I once discretized linear ODEs to solve matrix eigenvalues and hence imagine here it becomes nonlinear AE solved by FindRoot or I just misunderstood? But what's the machinery to turn it into some AE? BTW, I also encountered not small imaginary parts of eigenvalues when solving some discretized ODEs which should have real eigenvalues. But the small and large eigenvalues are usually very real if I remember correctly. A bit similar or maybe just coincidence.

Comment: Sorry, am I missing something? Tuning the cutoff value, the solution doesn't change at all?

Comment: @huotuichang Oh it's actually not a "ODE->PDE->AE" approach, it's just a differential equation -> difference equation i.e. finite difference method (FDM) approach (though I've named my function as `pdetoae`). You just need to remember `pdetoae` is something that'll replace derivative terms with corresponding difference formulas. If there's really a real solution, maybe we need a better initial guess for `FindRoot`, but I just tried to use the solution**s** when $d_i=0$ as initial guesses (yeah if you adjust options of `"Shooting"` in `NDSolve`, you'll be able to find 2 different solutions)…

Comment: @huotuichang …and `FindRoot` still find the 2 solutions above, so I feel a bit suspicous about whether there exists a real solution or not. As to the cutoff value, I think the solution should not be influenced much if it's really just a small number for overcoming the singularity?

Comment: @huotuichang Oh I've made a simple mistake in translating your equation,  check my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and prompt update. I misunderstood something previously and was also just about to ask you some weird things in the previous version. No suspicious stuff now as far as I can see. So the realness is for sure since you delete imaginary part? And when I set $d_i=0$, it basically can return to the solutions I found. But comparing them, I noticed that the leftmost part or the initial slope of Q1 curve doesn't match very well.

Comment: Using some completely different method for $d_i=0$ case in Matlab, the result is same to my code in this post, i.e., obviously steeper initial slope when increasing w1. Any comment or possible improvement will be greatly appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68932/discussion-between-xzczd-and-huotuichang).

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Any comment to my message [in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68932/discussion-between-xzczd-and-huotuichang)? Thanks.