# How to solve integro-differential with parameters iteratively?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, parametric-functions

I am trying to solve an integro-differential equation and tried using one of the answers that I found in a related question:

[Numerically solve an integro-differential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148541/numerically-solve-an-integro-differential-equation)

The difference is I have parameters outside the integral, so I used ParametricNDSolve instead of NDSolveValue. Here is a simplified example that captures the essence of the problem:

```
ydrive[t_] = Exp[-t^2/5]*Sin[2*Pi*t];(*driving term*)
reset[] := (Clear[ysol2];
  ysol2[n_] := 
   ysol2[n] = 
    ParametricNDSolve[{D[y[t], t] == 
       c*y[t] + \[Lambda]*ydrive[t] + 
        0.1*Integrate[ysol2[n - 1][\[Lambda], c1][t], {c1, -1., 1.}], 
      y[-10.^2] == 0}, y, {t, -100., 100.}, {\[Lambda], c}])
reset[]
ysol2[0] = # &;(*initial guess*)
```

When I display even the zeroth order iteration:

```
ysol2[0][1., 1.][0.]
```

It gives an error message, "Dependent variables {y,[Lambda]} cannot depend on parameters {
[Lambda],c}."

I hope anyone can help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: I'm wondering: The integral part here integrates over the ode-parameter c(not the dependent variabel t)?

Comment: This equation can be solved by numerical method but  interval `{t,-100,100}` is too large, for numerical model please let consider `{t,-10,10}` or even `{t,-5,5}`.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, I need to integrate over the parameter of the ODE. In the original problem, I need to integrate over wavevector k and solve the ODE in time t.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Sure. But that is not the main issue. For example, if you remove the Integrate part and consider only the ParametricNDSolve part, it works just fine even with the (-100,100) interval. My main problem is how to integrate an external parameter and do it iteratively to solve the integro-differential equation self-consistently.

Answer (score 2):

We can solve this equation by collocation method. Note, that we can exclude parameter $\lambda$, by substitution $y=\lambda u$. First we call

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"]; 
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];
```

Then we define collocation points and weights for Gauss integral, variables, equations and initial conditions as follows

```
np = 21; g = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, -1, 1]; points = 
 g[[All, 1]];
weights = g[[All, 2]];


vart = Table[u[i][t], {i, np}]; vart1 = 
 Table[u[i]'[t], {i, np}]; var = Table[u[i], {i, np}];

eqs = Table[
   vart1[[i]] == 
    points[[i]] vart[[i]] + ydrive[t] + .1 vart . weights, {i, np}];

ic = Table[vart[[i]] == 0 /. {t -> -100}, {i, np}];
```

Finally we solve system of equations

```
sol = NDSolve[{eqs, ic}, var, {t, -100, 100}];
```

In the small scale solution looks like

```
Table[Plot[Evaluate[vart[[i]] /. sol[[1]]], {t, -5, 5}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> Row[{"c = ", points[[i]]}]], {i, np}]
```

[image: Figure 1]
Visualization in the large scale

```
Table[LogPlot[Evaluate[vart[[i]] /. sol[[1]]], {t, -10, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> Row[{"c = ", points[[i]]}]], {i, np}]
```

[image: Figure 2]